# Selenium - webDriver not stable-error stack trace

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on the submit button inside the modal. It only works sometimes - it's not stable.

Below is my HTML element:

```html
<button id="submit-btn" name="submit" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm submit projectSaveBtn">Submit</button>
```

Here I'm using `id` for locating the element, but I'm not able to click on the submit button inside the modal.

My Java code:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("submit-btn"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element1).build().perform();   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element1)).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it was timing issue .Modal was opened before the page loaded properly so giving the time before clicking/opening modal solves the issue .

Here is my code -->

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);         
WebElement add = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.projectAddBtn")));
```

`add.click();`

This solved my issue.Thank you all for the support :-)

Answer (score 2):

When we use the action class, selenium takes mouse and keyboard controls. If we interact with mouse or keyboard at the time of test execution (specially the actions statement execution), it may fail some times.

You can try with actions class and don't interact until it completes the test execution. it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `id` attribute you can use an `xpath` as follows :

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit-btn']"));
element1.click();
```

or

```
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-info btn-sm submit projectSaveBtn' and @id='submit-btn']"));
element2.click();
```

Comment: still no luck .Its dismissing the modal without clicking into submit button

Comment: Why would you resort to `Actions` click(), even though it is a modal? Try `Java` click.

Comment: I thought its timing issues so i used actions there ..I tried with both the methods no luck

Comment: @AkshayKrishna `No luck` doesn't throws any light on what's wrong happening. Update the Question with the error stack trace.

Comment: WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit-btn']"));  

I tried this also ,first time it worked but its not stable

Comment: or you can try with javascript executor to click on it. It may give your 100% success always.

Comment: Hey guys can anybody help ?I am not able to solve the issue .After opening modal dialog if i click manually the button to submit without filling any data it should give alert but not giving.So is there anything i am  missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a windows modal dialog box, you might want to first `switchTo()` to the modal and then perform `accept()` on it.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().window("");
```

Comment: This might be the issue .Do we need to handle modal form in separate way?

Comment: How to switch from the parent page to the modal dialog page ?

Comment: Yes. The modal dialog box needs to be handled explicitly. "driver.switchTo().alert()" will move your focus from your browser window to the modal. Next accept() will send positive response to the modal. The second line will again get your focus to your browser window.

Comment: No .Its not required bcz modal is part of the same window or its in same HTML DOM so no need of switching .You can fetch directly like other elements.

Comment: Windows Modal Dialog Box is a functionality of the Operating System and not the browser. So it won't be visible in the dom. Probably you are referring to some other modal. My answer stands for windows modal.

Comment: Mine is browser modal not the windows modal